# Open built in gallery app with an album

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

How to open inbuilt gallery app with a specific album opened on screen ?

I know this code can be used for launching gallery app , but how to filter a specific album ? or open it ?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: do you have the that album Uri?

Comment: @SohailZahid what do you exactly mean ? Its a local album with some name

Comment: there sould be a content uri of that album.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your photos ares stored at `youCam` folder or it can be any folder

If you are compiling against API 23 or Greater then get runtime permision `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/youCam);`

```
File[] listFile = file.listFiles();
new HomeScreen.SingleMediaScanner(HomeScreen.this, listFile[0]);
...
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

        private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
        private File mFile;

        public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
            mFile = f;
            mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
            mMs.connect();
        }

        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
            mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
        }

        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            mMs.disconnect();
        }

    }
```

This will open you all images in that folder in default gallery.

Comment: Thanks for code , but my question is , there is an album already present under default gallery which is basically DCIM folder i guess I want to show that album

Comment: @vishal you just have to create a file of that folder location `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Camera/DCIM);`

Comment: how to give a path to this if I want to open a download  folder? When I tried this:    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/download"); It's throwing null pointer exception ,may be path is wrong., and how can create new folder/ album in gallery before I open it? @SohailZahid

Comment: @Sid are you compiling against API 23.

Comment: @Sid have get runtime permission then?

Comment: I am getting the path as  "storage/emulated/0/youCam" if I try to create a directory by file.mkdirs() , I am unable to see the folder created,, and dose not show any error. @SohailZahid

Comment: @Sid you can get that path using file explore properties [http://i.imgur.com/5hdCGEJ.png]

Comment: yes but still I am unable to see the folder in file explorer. @SohailZahid

Comment: @Sid you have to post you query as a new question with your code.

Comment: can you please help me with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627608/how-to-create-folder-in-external-storage-and-check-for-permission/37627751?noredirect=1#comment62737764_37627751@Sohail Zahid