# How to create folder in external storage and check for permission?

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception, user-permissions

I want to create a folder on click of photo's layout. 
And on click of layout new folder created should get open if it is empty it should show the toast or it should get open with images. For this I have created a new file and I am doing a scan for files, it is throwing a null pointer exception for the array of files.

```
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(path,"/MeaVita");



File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MeaVita");

File[] listFile = file1.listFiles();



    photosLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            checkFilePermissions();


              if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
                 dir.mkdirs();
              }


            if (listFile.length == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The folder is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    new MainActivity.SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, listFile[0]);
                }

        }
    });
```

methods

```
    public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        mMs.disconnect();
    }

}

private void checkFilePermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}
```

Log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.siddhi.meavita, PID: 15025
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                            at com.example.siddhi.meavita.Activities.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:119)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
```

EDIT:

```
  photosLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String folder_main = "MeaVita";
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);


            checkFilePermissions();

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

            if (listFile.length == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The folder is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                new MainActivity.SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, listFile[0]);
            }

        }
    });
```

This code works now , but it dose not ask for the permission then also it creates the folder. How?

Not getting what's going wrong help please..

Comment: show your MainActivity.java onClick() code

Comment: please check edited question. @SathishKumarJ

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(path,"/MeaVita");
 if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
             dir.mkdirs();
          }
```

add following line your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this may helps you.

EDIT 1:

It seems you are access empty/null File[] . you may modify the code structure like,

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File dir = new File(path,"/MeaVita");

 photosLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        checkFilePermissions();
          if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
             dir.mkdirs();
          }

        File file1 = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MeaVita");
        File[] listFile = file1.listFiles();

          if (listFile.length == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The folder is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                new MainActivity.SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, listFile[0]);
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: I have added this permissions in manifest.But this not help on marshmello further have to check permissions at runtime. @Sathish Kumar J

Comment: I also tried File[] listFile = dir.listFiles(); after the mkdirs(). @Sathish Kumar J

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(path,"/MeaVita");

photosLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

 if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
         dir.mkdirs();
     }


     if (listFile.length == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The folder is empty.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                new MainActivity.SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, listFile[0]);
            }
    }
  } else {
        checkFilePermissions();
```

} 
    });

Comment: i tried this still it throws npe. I also tried 
                File[] listFile = dir.listFiles(); after the mkdirs(). @Mây Và Bão

Comment: How about this ???                                                                                                          String folder_main = "MeaVita";

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}File[] listFile = file1.listFiles();

Comment: what's file1 in this? @Mây Và Bão

Comment: Sr my mistake . String folder_main = "MeaVita"; File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main); if (!dir .exists()) { dir.mkdirs(); }File[] listFile = dir .listFiles();

Comment: how can I arrange this code to ask for the permission, make directory and then open the folder? Now with this if folder is created it works well, but if folder is not created it throws npe on the array. @Mây Và Bão

Comment: checkFilePermissions() call just show dialog ask for permission, it not block main thread so after u call checkFilePermissions() it call next line code immediately. you should mkdir if you already have permission if not show some infomation for user. One more, you can check result from checkFilePermission through onActivityResult, more detail at :https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en